# CSS rollover sprites

Tags: css, sprite, rollover

I have used this effect before, everything is in order (As far as I see), but it's just not working. What have I missed?

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bRLc6/)

[Sprite here](http://www.euroworker.no/public/upload/login_sprite.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your sprite is arranged horizontally, you will want to offset the hover state like this:

```
element:hover {
background-position: -77px 0;
}
```

Comment: Note, the swapped order and the negative value. Both are needed.

Comment: It is a mistake I make all the time. I just think back to high school geometry and all those (x,y) coordinates.  background-position has the same order.

Answer (score 1):

Your background offset seems to be wrong - instead of 0 77px (which is a y-offset, along the wrong axis), try -77px 0.

Answer (score 1):

just change

```
background-position: 0 77px;
```

to

```
background-position: -77px 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Um, your background-position is adjusting the top starting position rather than the left starting position?